# Line plot with points sized on date axis - R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following dataset:

```
library(tidyverse)
the_dates <- c("2020-08-01","2020-08-02","2020-08-03","2020-08-04")
the_dates <- as.Date(the_dates)
solno <- c(3,4,2,3)
dataex <- data.frame(the_dates,solno)
```

I want to create a line chart, but with each point the size of its value. I tried the following code:

```
dataex %>% 
  ggplot(aes(the_dates, solno)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point(aes(shape=16), size = solno)
```

But I get an error: `Error: A continuous variable can not be mapped to shape`. I can't find the mistake, please could you help me?

Comment: You probably want to put `size = solno` *inside* `aes()` (& take `shape=16` out...)

Comment: `aes()` is used for mapping aesthetics *to columns in your data frame*. When you want a constant for a layer, don't put it inside `aes()`. Change your `geom_point` layer to `geom_point(aes(size = solno), shape = 16)`. Putting `shape = 16` inside `aes()`, ggplot will essentially create a column of data, with all the values as `16`, and put that for the shape aesthetic - but 16 is numeric (continuous), and as the error says, shapes must be categorical.

Comment: Thanks for the comments Z.Lin and Gregor Thomas, I understand now how `aes` maps variables in ggplot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was with the shape. This works.

```
dataex %>% ggplot(aes(the_dates,solno)) + geom_line() + 
  geom_point(shape = 16, aes(size = solno))
```

[image]